# Bash on Windows: mv command - cannot move to a subdirectory of itself

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install Ruby from sources on the Windows Linux Subsystem.
I've successfully built from source in my home directory: `~/ruby/ruby-2.3.0` and I'm trying to move it to `/opt/rubies/`.

When I run the move command I get the following error:

```
/# mv ~/ruby/ruby-2.3.0/ /opt/rubies/
mv: cannot move ‘/root/ruby/ruby-2.3.0/’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0’
```

This is super confusing as I'm moving the directory to a totally different location, not a subdirectory of itself, as the paths themselves show.

It does the same thing for any move command under my home directory:

```
~# mv test/ /
mv: cannot move ‘test/’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘/test’
```

And I can't seem to copy any files either:

```
~# cp ruby/ruby-2.3.0/ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0
cp: omitting directory ‘ruby/ruby-2.3.0/’
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try without the trailing `/` on the source argument. With that there, you are telling the OS to move the contents of the directory but not specifying the files, and not the directory. That's actually a convention that many unix systems follow across commands.

So instead of: `mv ~/ruby/ruby-2.3.0/ /opt/rubies/`

try: `mv ~/ruby/ruby-2.3.0 /opt/rubies/`

You also need to make sure that you are not running the command with PWD = ~/ruby/ruby-2.3.0 because then you are trying to move the directory you are in. `cd ~; mv ~/ruby/ruby-2.3.0 /opt/rubies/`

Comment: I've tried all combinations of trailing slashes - with and without - and it still gives the same error. In the first example I was running the command from `PWD = /` so I wasn't inside the directory being moved.

Answer (score 2):

#### Am I doing something wrong?

```
mv ~/ruby/ruby-2.3.0/ /opt/rubies/
```

You need to remove **both** trailing `/`s.

Does directory `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0` already exist? Check by running:

```
ls /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0
```

If it does exist run the following command to remove it:

```
rm -rf /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0
```

Now use the following command to do the move:

```
mv ~/ruby/ruby-2.3.0 /opt/rubies
```

This will create the directory `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0`

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [ls](http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html) - List information about files.
- [mv](http://ss64.com/bash/mv.html) - Move or rename files or directories.
- [rm](http://ss64.com/bash/rm.html) - Remove files (delete/unlink)

Comment: It fails both with and without the trailing slashes. I've confirmed that the destination directory is empty as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses everyone, but it turns out that this is a bug with the beta version of Bash on Windows.

One of the developers posted a [comment to their issue tracker on 2016-04-11](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/104):

> We have a fix internally on one of our dev branches. Should hit the insiders builds before too long.